Identify this Dirty Dozen-like Italian (?) movie
I have bought a VHS of the Italian movie Fuoco incrociato (AKA Cross Mission) and although the movie was OK, I was more intrigued by the plot on the back of the VHS cover. It seems that there has been a mix-up and that the wrong plot (with the wrong screens) winded up on the VHS.
I found my cover online:

The upload is not mine, but I can scan my version if needed. Since not many of you will speak Dutch, here's my translation:

Kelly (a freelance journalist), Luger (a German assassin), Flynn (an
  experienced mercenary) and Garcia (a professional Guerilla) have one
  thing in common: they are all searching for the mysterious Tambopata
  who has created an entire empire during the civil war which he
  sponsers with drugs money since he has one of the best connections to
  Miami. Tambopata is protected by an army of bodyguards so the four
  need to form a unit to get to the druglord. They succeed when they use
  Kelly as bait, but their little alliance falls apart when each one of
  the three guys wants to take the body of Tambopata home to collect the
  reward.

When checking the cast list on IMDB you'll see that there are no characters called Kelly, Luger, ... I have done a IMDB character search on the Tambopata but to no avail
There appears to be a French VHS with a same plot as the plot on my Dutch VHS. The title of the French VHS is Mafia Power and appearantly it's an alternate title of.. Cross Mission! That still isn't the real plot of Cross Mission ofcourse.

Here's my translation of the French summary:

A female journalist succeeds in identifying a mysterious drug lord
  whose face has never been seen. He reigns the country with an army of
  followers but the CIA doesn't agree with his schemes. They put
  together a special ops to stop the druglord.

Now what is the question?
The plot on IMDB (the one about General Romero) is correct. That is the movie I have seen. However, this is not by far the same plot that is to be found on the Dutch and the French VHS. What I would want to know is what the title is of the movie that corresponds with the plot of the Dutch and French VHS and why that plot ended up on the apparently wrong VHS.

Fun question. :) IMDb seems to be convinced that Cross Mission and Mafia Power are one and the same.

Yeah, I noticed it too (see the edited question) but as far as I can tell they have different plots. Never thought it would be this hard to locate the correct movie :)

I don't completely understand the question. Do you mean you found your answer or is there anything more to ask. In the former case, feel free to put it up as an answer. In the latter (or any) case you might want to elaborate on the actual question you're asking.

No, I didn't found my answer. There is a movie called Cross Mission which I have on a Dutch VHS. The plot and screens however are from a different movie. There is a French VHS called Mafia Power (which is just an alternate title of Cross Mission) which has a same plot as my Dutch VHS. Is this clear enough?

@TimothyPersoon - Actually, that only served to make it less clear. Please, concisely restate your question. What are we actually supposed to be identifying? Are you looking for the American equivalent? Sounds to me as though they messed up on the cover, though there really isn't a move which corresponds to the text. Very cool you found all of this stuff, but I am not really getting the question. Also, as far as the screen shots on the back, these are usually taken not from the film, but from stills. Also, if you look at the red dress on the front, it almost matches the one on the back.

Edited the question and formatted some info. Hope this is clears things up?

Yeah, that makes quite a bit more sense, thank you. I hope you don't mind that I added a little futher question at the end. Feel free to remove it if you don't like it.

I don't mind the question, but I don't think it can be answered

@TimothyPersoon "I don't think it can be answered" - Why not? There has to be a reason for that, it's not just a coincidence when it's multiple versions of the VHS that have the wrong plot. There has to be some relation between the two movies.

Yeah, I guess you're right about that. Either way, I'm curious if we're ever gonna get an answer

Some "second zones" movies were poorly translated. It's quite fun to watch them or their differences (there are special website about them, etc.) My guess, is that even before "Google Translate", people were doing some mistakes and no one check them.

Oddly enough, Richard Randall's IMDB page has only 2 film credits, neither of which appear to co-star Alex Vitale, nor are they directed by Al Bradley.  The mystery deepens...  Where's @Trish Ling?!?

@JohnnyBones I've been looking! Haven't had much luck though...

You are not the only person to own this video., the linked review is fairly in-depth.
I looked up Alex Vitale, whose name is on the back cover.  He's done nothing remotely close to anything described in either version of Cross Mission.
I looked up Richard Randall, whose name is on the back cover.  He was in a movie called Fuoco Incrociato in 1988, which was also released in other countries as Cross Mission. 
I then found this brief review on a Cult Classic webstore, which seems to corroborate what's on the box, and even includes a bit about a dwarf (which, to me, indicates the reviewer actually watched the movie since that part isn't on the box).  The dwarf, however, is mentioned in the first review linked above.
From that review, I looked up Brigitte Porsche on IMDB.  Her only movie was Fuoco Incrociato.
I then found this user's review, where he/she talks of a female reporter and several mercenaries, and certain other plot points that seem to overlap between IMDB and the movie's covers.
My conclusion, therefore, is that this was likely the product of poor translation (or Engrish, as it has become known), coupled with possibly a little liberty on the part of the copywriter.  You'll note that even the two covers you've posted don't match each other in detail; one states a team is put together by the CIA and the other mentions no such agency.  
For further proof, see the Covers Always Lie trope, which has links to several similar disconnects between packaging and movie (although this specific movie isn't listed, it still proves that this isn't a unique occurrence).

The OP says the movie synopsis for Fuoco Incrociato is the one on the tape (and links to the same IMDB page as you). The one thing I note is that the cast and director section at left of the box synopsis is a) in English and b) is correct for the movie on the cassette. The problem is that the box synopsis is for a different movie and the OP want to know which one. "Tambopata" is a place not a person, so I am tempted to say the person who wrote/translated it probably was faking it (ala Fake Sign Language Guy).

@Yorik - Yes, I understand what he means.  However, there is no movie on IMDB that stars both Alex Vitale and Richard Randall, as I pointed out above, and both those names are on the back cover.  So, that may not be correct, contrary to your assumption.

All the reviews you link are indeed about Cross Mission (or the Italian title Fuoco Incrociato) and that is indeed the movie that's on the tape itself. However, the movie does not correspond with the box synopsys of the French and Dutch VHS and that's the movie I want to know about

@TimothyPersoon - The point is, after exhaustive research the only conclusion is that they are the same.  Tambopata is not a person, it's a region of Peru.  The copywriter made up the rest to fit it into the allotted space.  See the Covers Always Lie trope for proof of that.

@JohnnyBones I'm sorry, but I can't believe that a writer would just start inventing names like Luger and in such detail (German assassin etc). This is not just a case of someone writing a plot about a movie he hasn't seen but an entire new plot. I agree with the cover bit but.. as someone pointed out earlier: the red dress of the female on the cover looks the same as one of the screens and those are not in the movie
